# Unable to start activity - NullPointExeption

Tags: android

i tried to create a new activity..

i dont really know how i can fix this problem..

on Android Studio it shows no errors at all but when i try to run it LogCat shows following:

```
10-19 21:21:34.427  10423-10423/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iklikla.eightgame/com.iklikla.eightgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2330)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5368)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.iklikla.eightgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5284)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my MainActivity.class:

```
package com.iklikla.eightgame;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button infos = (Button) findViewById(R.string.infos);
    infos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toAnotherActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), InfoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(toAnotherActivity, 0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And my InfoActivity.class:

```
package com.iklikla.eightgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class InfoActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_infos);
}
}
```

Comment: `on Android Studio it shows no errors at all but when i try to run it LogCat shows following`.  No errors in the compiler does not mean no errors when you run your app.  If it did, then no app would ever crash! `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.iklikla.eightgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)` - this shows you exactly what error you have and where it is happening.  onCreate(), line 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button infos = (Button) findViewById(R.string.infos);
```

R.string.info is the id of a string in your resources.

Don't you mean R.**id**.infos ?